# can not add SVN repository WSIG in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github, svn, eclipse-plugin, agents-jade

I am trying to add repository WSIG to Eclipse but i get this error unable to load default SVN client.

- link [WSIG](https://github.com/mhzworld/wsig-examples) repository  in github

[image]

Comment: As I see you are using .git url..and as SVN repo? Since this is a Git repository why SVN?

Comment: Is there a way to use URL from GitHub on Eclipse ? Or should use git ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes as explained above you'll need a Eclipse Plugin to clone the git repository.
Or Install latest eclipse from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2018-12/R/eclipse-inst-win64.exe) and use the already installed plugin.

But as it is mentioned it a GIT repo not SVN thus SVN plugin will not work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the repository you're trying to `clone` (in git terms) or checkout (in SVN) is a `GIT repository`. That means, it uses Git as its version control system.

Thus, you cannot use SVN plugin for that, for basic understanding you can go through [here](https://dzone.com/articles/version-control-git-vs-svn).

Also on github there are ample of ways to get hands-on on Git , which I'll recommend before you actually start working using Git.
Here is the link : https://try.github.io/

Now, for your question you have to do as below for importing in eclipse :

- First see , whether you have EGit plugin already installed in your eclipse if not please get this installed, as :

[image]

- Once thats setup, then Goto --> Import -> Git --> Projects from Git

[image]

- Then Clone URI

[image]

- Then add your project link which you see on git hub as :

[image]

- now paste the URL here. Since we selected http while copying from Github then choose same here as below :

[image]

- Now feed your user credential and you are all set.
- If you still face any difficulty within above steps, there is good documentation with images here as well :  https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html#github

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello @Abderrahmen , is the issue resolved? Are you able to access the project from github :) ?